# How to clear the plotted line at every nth x value so looks clearly broken into segments?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot where the X axis represents over time, and it is broken into segments of 10 periods, and it resets every 10 periods at 0. When it draws the lines, at the end of the segment, it draws the line going to 0 as per the reset. Here is an image, with 3 lines being plotted, and vertical gray lines showing where every 10th interval is:

[image]

What I would like to do is to hide or erase the line in the 9 th interval, so it would not look draw the line gong back to the zero line. For example, when the blue line gets very high or low just before the gray vertical marker, it should stop, not draw back down to 0.

Is this possible in Python? For the image above, I'm using matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks -- that works exactly as I was hoping

Comment: @Ondro Please post your comment as an answer. I would also suggest re-shapping your data into a 2D array and taking advantage of `plot`'s irrationally flexible signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate segments with NaN values... Here is two segments example:

```
plt.plot([0,1,2,np.NaN,2,3,4,5],[5,4,5,np.NaN,2,3,6,4])
```